# event of NSTableViewCell edition completed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

There is a `NSTextFieldCell` in `NSTableView`, and it is Editable. By double-click the `NSTextFieldCell` user can change the content of it, How do I know the time when the edition completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dasblinkenlight's answer you most likely have the method you need, but in case you should need to catch the editing events, you can get all the normal delegate methods of `NSControl` called, for instance:

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

It does exactly what you are asking for - it notifies you when the editing is completed. More in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing Apple's example code, I found a easy way: just make a method

```
 - (IBAction)textTitleChanged:(id)sender;
```

and bind NSTextFieldCell 's selector to it.